# Find a counter example of an infinite-dimensional vector space $V$ and a linear form $f: V\rightarrow F$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given an infinite-dimensional vector space $V$, show that there exists a linear form $f: V\rightarrow F$ such that $f \neq f_{v_0}$ for all $v_0 \in V$ where $f_{v_0}(v) = \langle v, v_0 \rangle$

I thought about the case where $V = \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $f : \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_a(p(x)) = p(a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ but I don't know if it's right.

thanks!

Comment: What is $f_{v}$?

Comment: sorry forgot to explain that haha I will edit my post

Comment: So $V$ is a prehilbert space?

Comment: if that's an Inner product space then yes!

Comment: So are you asking to give an example of the failure of the Riesz Representation Theorem when the inner-product space is not complete?

Comment: We haven't learned that yet so I can't really tell you if that's what i'm asking

Comment: I assume by linear form you mean continuous linear functional? Or any linear functional?

Comment: any linear functional

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $1, x, x^2,\cdots$. Let inner product be $\langle \sum a_n x^n, \sum b_n x^n\rangle =\sum a_n b_n$ (with appropriate limits of $\sum$).

Consider a linear functional $f \colon \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$; $f(p(x)) = p(1)$. The evaluation at $1$ is the sum of all the coefficients; i.e. $f(p(x)) = \langle p(x), 1+ x+ x^2 + \cdots + x^n + x^{n+1}q(x)\rangle$, when $\deg p \le n$ and $q$ be any polynomial. This holds for any $p(x)$, i.e. for any degree.

We want $f(p(x)) = \langle p(x), p_0(x)\rangle$ for some $p_0(x)$. But any candidates of degree $k$ fails for $p(x)$ with degree greater than $k$. Note that $$1+ x+ x^2 + x^3 + \cdots \not \in \mathbb{R}[x].$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Thanks to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $f_{v}$ is continuous, and $\lVert f_v \rVert = \lVert v \rVert$. So you are done if you can construct a non-continuous linear functional on a given vector space. And it can be done on every infinite-dimensional vector space with the axiom of choice.

Comment: @jinksmaster Can you construct a non-continuous linear functional?